# PDO insert statement not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-table, isset

I have a page called waiting.php this page is the portal to starting a real life session between a counsellor and a student. I have a submit button that is called "name='submit'

I have a piece of code that calls for the submit button to be (isset) once that happens then I want the PDO statement to execute the insert query. However I check phpmyadmin and nothing is being inserted.

My code goes as like so :

```
f(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO counselors (counselorname) VALUES (:counselorname)");
    $query->bindParam(':counselorname', $_POST['namedrop']);
    $query->execute();
    }
```

Now this is the actual code that makes the submit button and the drop menu for the counselors names :

```
echo "<td> 
                <form method= 'post'>
                    </form><select name='namedrop'>
                        <option value=''>Counselor Name</option> 
                        <option value='dmin-John'>Admin - John</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Christine'>Admin - Christine</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Dawne'>Admin - Dawne</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Cherie'>Counselor - Cherie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Tootie'>Counselor - Tootie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Debbie'>Counselor - Debbi</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Delores'>Front Desk - Delores</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Kiana'>Front Desk - Kiana</option>
                    </select> 
                </form>";

echo "<td> <form action='counselor.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' method='post' target='_new'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start Session'>
            </form> </td>";
```

I'm new to PHP so my logic is some what there but my syntax and know how of how to implement my logic is below average.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit :

and this is how the page looks :

[image: Waiting.php]

Edit 2:

```
echo "<td> 
            <form action='counselor.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' method='post' target='_new'>
                    <select name='namedrop'>
                        <option value=''>Counselor Name</option> 
                        <option value='dmin-John'>Admin - John</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Christine'>Admin - Christine</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Dawne'>Admin - Dawne</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Cherie'>Counselor - Cherie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Tootie'>Counselor - Tootie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Debbie'>Counselor - Debbi</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Delores'>Front Desk - Delores</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Kiana'>Front Desk - Kiana</option>
                    </select> 

            <td> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start Session'>
            </form> </td>";
}

  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO counselors (id, counselorname) VALUES (:id, :counselorname)");
    $query = $dbh->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
    $query->bindParam(':counselorname', $_POST['namedrop']);
    $query->execute();
    }
```

Comment: You can't pass the `id` through a `GET` method and then `POST` it. You need to include the `id` as a hidden input value.

Comment: the id is just something I am going to use to join tables, what I have set up with the ID is to have it be url so that when the counselor is ready to pick up the student I can select the students information via the $_GET['id']; I dont understand what that has to do with inserting though since I am not inserting the actual id.

Comment: The ID variable should not have anything to do with this code. So how you pass this variable is not essential.

Comment: You should look into [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) to help determine the cause of the failure.

Comment: error handling is on, i am just not getting any errors at all in my logs.

Comment: Found the answer. ty for the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that : action="counselor.php?id= ". $row['id'] . "

meaning that the insert script was supposed to go to the counselor.php page. reason why it wasnt shooting errors is that what i told it do was working accept not in the way I wanted it to.

second problem is that the form must be in method=post if not the ID will insert but not the name. so to fix this  :

```
echo "
        <td>    <form action='counselor.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "' method='post' target='_new'>
                    <select name='namedrop'>
                        <option value=''>Counselor Name</option> 
                        <option value='dmin-John'>Admin - John</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Christine'>Admin - Christine</option>
                        <option value='Admin-Dawne'>Admin - Dawne</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Cherie'>Counselor - Cherie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Tootie'>Counselor - Tootie</option>
                        <option value='Counselor-Debbie'>Counselor - Debbi</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Delores'>Front Desk - Delores</option>
                        <option value='FrontDesk-Kiana'>Front Desk - Kiana</option>
                    </select>
            </td>

            <td> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Start Session'></td>
            </form> </td>";
```

then on my counselor.php i ran a test to check if I am getting anything with :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo "$id";

$name = $_POST['namedrop'];
echo "$name";
```

[image: check]

then all i did to run the query was :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO counselors (id, counselorname) VALUES (:id, :counselorname)");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
    $query->bindParam(':counselorname', $_POST['namedrop']);
    $query->execute();
    }
```

and then here is the finished result :

[image: finish]

Comment: Also this is not complete yet as I will have to "sanitize" the id and enter in validation to check if it is a number obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is flawed. Your $query statement expects `namedrop` but this select list is not part of the same form as your submit button.

Your code shows 3 different forms, and not a single one is complete.

```
<form method="post" action="..." target="_new">
    -- All components and elements must be declared inside this node
</form>
```

Comment: found the problem. ty for trying!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array of your binds to execute statement directly:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO counselors (counselorname) VALUES (:counselorname)");
    $query->execute(array(':counselorname', $_POST['namedrop']));
}
```

Comment: i found the problem. ty for trying